# ros::Walltime differs from chrono::clock?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I recently wanted to improve the computational efficiency of IPOPT solver and my costumed mpc_local_planner. Before that my mpc_local_node was taking 0.3-0.5s per iteration, which obviously does not meet the requirements of real-time control.

So I checked the running time of each function of the code and found that IPOPT actually only uses 20-40ms to calculate the optimal solution.

```
Total seconds in IPOPT                               = 0.025
```

And within the same function I used four different time output methods and found that ros::walltime and chrono::clock are exactly ten times different. Is chrono::clock the correct time? And ros::walltime is slowed down by a factor of 10 for some reason?

Here is my Code for time output:

```
    ros::Time end1 = ros::Time::now();
    ros::WallTime wall_end = ros::WallTime::now();
    auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "Duration_loop(ros Time): " << end1.sec - begin1.sec << "." << end1.nsec - begin1.nsec << "s" << std::endl;
    cout << "Duration_loop(ros WallTime): " << wall_end << ", " << wall_end.sec - wall_begin.sec << "." << wall_end.nsec - wall_begin.nsec << "s" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Duration loop(CPU Time): "  << float( clock () - begin_time_2 ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "s" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Duration loop(Chrono CPU Time): " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_end-t_start).count() << "ms"<< std::endl;
```

And the Output (chrono time is in ms):

```
Duration_loop(ros Time): 0.43000000s
Duration_loop(ros WallTime): 1673347284.124544067, 0.43919478s
Duration loop(CPU Time): 0.033641s
Duration loop(Chrono CPU Time): 43.9134ms
```

I use *gazebo* and `use_sim_time = true`, so there are some differences between ros::Time and ros::Walltime.

Could someone help me, and thank you very much in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411217/ros::walltime-differs-from-chrono::clock?/) by [tang](https://answers.ros.org/users/133828/tang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> cout << "Duration_loop(ros Time): " << end1.sec - begin1.sec << "." << end1.nsec - begin1.nsec << "s" << std::endl;

Both the integer and decimal sides of this calculation are not valid. The correct way to calculate this is:

```
double d = (end1 - begin1).toSec();
```

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tang](https://answers.ros.org/users/133828/tang/) on 2023-01-11**:
It works! Thank you very much for the explanation.